# How to enforce flex wrap?

Tags: css, flexbox

My `flex` element contains 4 images. I want these 4 images to be displayed on two rows instead of one. Is it possible to enforce such a thing with `flex`?

```
<div>
<img src="image1.jpg />
<img src="image2.jpg />
<img src="image3.jpg />
<img src="image4.jpg />
</div>

div {
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your `<img>` tags you can put `flex: 1 50%;` and then on your `<div>` you put `flex-wrap: wrap;` or you can just put a `<br />` after your first 2 img tags

EDIT:

```
<div>
<div class='container'><img src="image1.jpg />
<div class='container'><img src="image2.jpg />
<div class='container'><img src="image3.jpg />
<div class='container'><img src="image4.jpg />
</div>

div {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container {
   flex: 1 50%;
}
```

something like this might work?

Comment: It sort of works but my images are now deformed (width/height ratio lost). I can't use a <br /> as this will mess with my responsive design

Comment: @drake035 see edit

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="flex">
    <img src="image1.jpg">
    <img src="image2.jpg">
    <img src="image3.jpg">
    <img src="image4.jpg">
</div>

<style>
    .flex {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .flex > img {
        display: flex;
        flex-basis: 50%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It sort of works but my images are now deformed (width/height ratio lost)

Comment: You probably have to create `div` container for each image and apply flex-basic to these divs.